# Why should I use datetime in SQL?

Tags: sqlite, validation, datetime

I was testing to see if I could pass strings into my sqlite database into the following table:

```
CREATE TABLE TIMES(
    ID              INT             PRIMARY KEY                 ,
    TIME_START      DATETIME        DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP   ,
    TIME_STOP       DATETIME                                    ,
    CONSTRAINT FUTURE_DATE CHECK
        (TIME_START >= CURRENT_TIMESTAMP AND TIME_STOP >= CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)
);
```

As so:

```
INSERT INTO TIMES VALUES (1, "2016-07-31 07:08:00", NULL)
```

It passed through, no problem. I was slightly stunned to see this so I tried another value:

```
INSERT INTO TIMES VALUES (2, "9999999999 07:08:00", NULL)
```

And it passed through as well. This got me worried as it is supposed to only allow `DATETIME` values in, not a bunch of numbers. I tried some other values:

```
INSERT INTO TIMES VALUES (3, "9999999999:::::::::", NULL);
INSERT INTO TIMES VALUES (4, "9999999999 99:99:99", NULL);
INSERT INTO TIMES VALUES (6, "this is some really random text", NULL);
INSERT INTO TIMES VALUES (6, "9999999999999999999", NULL);
```

All but the last one worked. My question is, why use date time when it doesn't validate the type of data coming in? Can't just use `CHAR` (in fact, `CHAR` has more constraints than `DATETIME`, it limits the amount of characters)?

All these are tested on:

- http://sqliteonline.com/
- Python's `sqlite3`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SQLite uses [dynamic typing](http://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html); it does not matter whether you use DATETIME or CHAR¹ or FLUFFY BUNNIES.

If you want to enforce that a value is in any of the [supported formats](http://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html#datetime), you could add an explicit constraint to check that some [built-in date function](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html) is able to parse it:

```
CREATE TABLE Times(
    Time_Stop  DATETIME  CHECK (date(Time_Stop) IS NOT NULL),
    [...]
);
```

---

¹ And CHAR(x) does *not* limit the length.

Comment: Why should I type anything then? Is there any advantage in doing so? (Other than knowing what types should be where)

Comment: For compatibility with other SQL DBs.